Getting repeated error message popup after update
I ran an update and upgrade yesterday as usual, but now I keep getting popups on my Kubuntu 22.04.4 with the following error message from Discover:
Failed to update 1 package
Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/nvidia-powerd', which is also in package nvidia-kernel-common-560 560.35.03-0ubuntu1 

How do I fix this? My GPU is a GTX 1650.
